# Linear non-causal system

Tags: linearity

Suppose we have a linear non-causal system with an input x(t) and an output y(t). If the input is zero up until t=a, must the output be zero before to because of linearity? Or can the output take nonzero value before t=a because the system can anticipate the future that x(t) will be nonzero after t=a?

Comment: If y(t) = x(t) + 3 then y(t) will be 3 when x(t) is zero. That doesn't make it non-linear.

Comment: @Andyaka, That is actually a nonlinear system, because if you took two inputs \$x_1(t)\$ and \$x_2(t)\$ and calculated the corresponding outputs \$y_1(t)\$ and \$y_2(t)\$, then considered the input \$x_1(t)+x_2(t)\$, the output will not be \$y_1(t)+y_2(t)\$. (Or, in shorter terms, it's nonlinear because you can't apply the superposition principle on that system)

Comment: But you could have the system \$y(t) = x(t+3)\$, and that is a linear system that has a nonzero output before the output becomes nonzero.

Comment: @Andyaka, the system you have mentioned is an incrementally linear system which is not linear system.

Comment: Linear systems can have an offset.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: if you're being a dynamic systems purist, no, they cannot, because a system with offset doesn't obey superposition.  But a system that's linear + offset is known as an affine system, and it's easy-peasy to make it exactly linear, and most circuits people take affine to be the same as linear (as you just did).  But to the **purist** -- nope.

Comment: I guess I am a realist who has used Linear Tech’s ADC’s that have gain and offset and not a purist.

Comment: Doesn't really sound like an EE question to me. Can anyone explain how this is relevant to this site?

Comment: @TonyStewart Tim's comment is exactly correct. Offset violates the idea of homogeneity, which is one of the two key ideas required by linearity. Mathematicians go to great lengths to craft precision into their statements so that proven properties remain valid over a wide range of discussion. When you give up on something vitally assumed, then all those properties relying upon them are also gone with it.

Comment: @Andyaka, signals and systems is one of the fundamental courses taught in an EE curriculum. Don't give in to the urge to think the scope of the field of EE is "stuff that I know".

Comment: Linear systems for DC , yes I agree for DC must have offset nulled. Now back to the future with... non-causal with this question.

Answer (score 1):

> If the input is zero up until t=to, must the output be zero before to because of linearity?

The output can be any function of the form

$$y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t-\tau)x(\tau)d\tau$$

and still be a linear (but not causal) system.

For a causal system, we'd have \$h(t') = 0\$ for \$t'<0\$, and then if the input were 0 from \$-\infty\$ up to some time \$t_0\$, the output would also be 0 for \$t<t_0\$.

Comment: If the system is linear and not causal, can h(t') be nonzero for t'<0 ?

Comment: @AhmadEldesokey, think about what the word "causal" means.

Comment: Causal means that the system can not anticipate the future and if the system is not causal, it can predict that x(t) will take some nonzero value in the future. Therefore h(t') can be nonzero for t'<0. Please, read my question again.

Comment: Yes you have it right. So the requirement that y(t) is zero at times before x(t) has a nonzero value comes from causality, not from linearity. One common use of noncausal systems is in image processing where \$t\$ is a spatial variable rather than a time variable. If you're doing image processing there's no reason to restrict yourself to filters where the output only depends on inputs to the left of the output location being calculated.

Comment: @AhmadEldesokey: so, you've just answered your own question!  Read your question and your comment, and put two and two together.